# Preventing a Ghostscript command from entering the Ghostscript command line interface after execution

Tags: ghostscript

Whenever I execute a Ghostscript command, like the one below, in the Windows command line window, upon completion it automatically enters into the Ghostscript command line interface (**GS >**, as shown in the screenshot below). I wonder if there is a way to prevent ghostscript from doing it.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Realized that the dNoCancel flag should be removed. Once it's removed, it no longer enters the gs command line interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that the interpreter starts up and, if any actions have been specified on the command line those are executed as part of initialisation. This includes running any files. Then the interpreter returns to the interactive prompt awaiting further input.

There is plenty of documentation available for Ghostscript (possibly too much). If you go [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.27/Use.htm#Interaction_related_parameters) then the switches relating to interaction with the user are described.